# Is integral homology trivial if homology with different coefficients is trivial?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Assume $C_*$ is a chain complex of abelian groups and $R$ is a ring.

Assume 
$$
H_k(C_*;R)=0
$$
for some $k\geq 0$.

Is it true that
$$
H_k(C_*;\mathbb{Z})=0?
$$

Comment: Take $R=\mathbb{Z}_3$ and look a the homology of $\mathbb{R}P^2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this can easily fail.  For instance, if $R$ is the zero ring, then $H_k(C_*;R)=0$ no matter what $C_*$ is.  A bit less trivially, if $R=\mathbb{Q}$, then $H_k(C_*;R)\cong H_k(C_*;\mathbb{Z})\otimes\mathbb{Q}$, so any chain complex with $H_k(C_*;\mathbb{Z})$ a nonzero torsion group will give a counterexample.